# ¿Else en un bucle While? - Python

Tags: python-3.x, while, else

Tengo una duda... en un bucle while en python.
¿Porqué en un bucle while cuando es infinito el "Else" no rompe el bucle y es necesario usar un break, pero cuando el bucle es finito, el else si rompe el bucle?
Acá tengo un par de ejemplos (Si es un error en la programación, ser amables :c)

```py
#While finito (un valor de c menor a 5), como yo  lo veo debe ser infinito :/   
c = int(input())
while c <= 5:
    c += 1
    print("c vale",c)
else:
    print("Se ha completado toda la iteración y c vale",c)
    c = c - 4
print ('vale',c)
```

```
#While Infinito (Ejemplo ligeramente modificado para comprobar que no rompe el bucle)
 print("Bienvenido al menú interactivo")
while(True):
    print("""¿Qué quieres hacer? Escribe una opción
    1) Saludar
    2) Sumar dos números
    3) Salir""")
    opcion = input()
    if opcion == '1':
        print("Hola, espero que te lo estés pasando bien")
    elif opcion == '2':
        n1 = float(input("Introduce el primer número: "))
        n2 = float(input("Introduce el segundo número: "))
        print("El resultado de la suma es: ",n1+n2)
    elif opcion =='3':
        print("¡Hasta luego! Ha sido un placer ayudarte")
        break
    else:
        print("Comando desconocido, vuelve a intentarlo")
print('salió del bucle')
```

Gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo del todo tu duda, pero creo que se debe a una comprensión incorrecta de la sentencia `else`.

Esa sentencia puede aparecer como parte de una estructura `if` o como parte de una estructura `while`, pero su significado es radicalmente distinto.

- `else` como parte de un `if`. Este es el uso más habitual y conocido por todo el mundo. Simplemente las órdenes del bloque `else` se ejecutarán *solo si* la condición del `if` es falsa.
- `else` como parte de un `while`. Esta es una característica única de Python (hasta donde yo se) y según algunos bastante anti-intuitiva. El bloque de código del `else` se ejecutará **después de que el bucle haya finalizado** y *solo si* la condición del bucle es falsa (lo que implica que no se ha salido del `while` mediante un `break`).

  El `else` en este caso **nunca rompe el bucle**, sino que sirve para detectar si se ha abandonado porque se había roto con `break`, o porque la condición del `while` se hizo falsa.

  Es decir, lo siguiente:

  ```
  while condicion:
      # Instrucciones del while
  else:
      # Instrucciones del while-else
  ```

  Es ejecutado por python como si dijera:

  ```
  while condicion:
      # Instrucciones del while
  if not condicion:
      # Instrucciones del while-else
  ```

  Pero realmente debemos leerlo mentalmente como:

  ```
  while condicion:
      # Instrucciones del while
  si no se abortó con break:
      # Instrucciones del while-else
  ```

Un ejemplo de uso del `while/else`:

```
i = 1
while i <= 3:
  txt = input("Escribe SI: ")
  if txt == "SI":
     print("Ok, lo has escrito en el intento", i)
     break
  i = i + 1
else:
  print("Has agotado tus tres intentos")
```

Aquí se le da al usuario tres oportunidades de escribir la palabra "SI". Si el `txt` introducido por el usuario es "SI", entonces se aborta el bucle. En ese caso la cláusula `else` (que pertenece al `while` y no al `if`) no será ejecutada. Sin embargo si introduce mal el texto tres veces seguidas, ya que `i` se va incrementando en cada iteración, llegará un momento en que no se cumple la condición del `while i<=3` , y se terminará el bucle. Si esto llega a suceder, se ejecutará la cláusula `else` del `while`.

Otros lenguajes que no tienen este "else raro", implementarían el ejemplo anterior de la siguiente forma:

```
i = 0
while i<=3:
  txt = input("Escribe SI: ")
  if txt == "SI":
     print("Ok, lo has escrito en el intento", i)
     break
  i = i + 1
if not i<=3:  # Si no se ha roto con break
  print("Has agotado tus tres intentos")
```

### Respecto a tus ejemplos

- El primer ejemplo tiene un `else` del tipo `while`. Ya que el bucle no contiene ningún `break`, el bucle terminará siempre de forma "normal", por lo que la parte del `else` se ejecutará siempre. Pero recuerda que se ejecuta **una vez el bucle ya finalizó**, por tanto aunque modifiques el valor de `c`, eso no va a causar que se vuelva a ejecutar el bucle.

  En este ejemplo en particular lo mismo daría que las instrucciones que has metido en el `else` estuvieran ya fuera del bucle. Se van a ejecutar siempre (una vez que el bucle termine), porque el bucle nunca es roto con `break`.
- El segundo ejemplo no tiene ningún `else` del tipo `while`. Aunque aparece un `else` en el código, está asociado a la secuencia `if/elif/else`, por tanto no guarda ninguna relación con la pregunta.

  Pero ten en cuenta además que si hubieras usado un `else` tipo `while`, por ejemplo así:

  ```
  while True:
    # Ordenes del bucle, las que sean
  else:
    print("Bucle terminado normalmente")
  ```

  realmente no tendría sentido. Esa parte `else` no podría ejecutarse nunca, ya que el bucle **no puede terminar normalmente**, pues es un bucle infinito. Sólo podrá terminarse mediante un `break`, en cuyo caso la parte del `else` no será ejecutada.

Answer (score 0):

1. While(true) significa que siempre se repite.
2. Almacena tu valor booleano en una variable Ej. "val"==true y tu sentencia seria while(val)
3. de esa manera en tu else a parte de usar break; podrias agregar el codigo

   ```
   val=false;
   ```
4. una vez explicado esto te dire cual es la diferencia no es por que sea finito, si no que en tu else en tu segundo ejemplo no cambia su condicion a compracion del primer while que usas como ejemplo en el cual sigues manipulando tu condicion.

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta. En el primer ejemplo el código del `else` no manipula la condición. Aunque cambie el valor de  `c`, eso no afecta al `while` previo porque _ya terminó de ejecutarse_. El `else` del `while` se ejecuta ya fuera del bucle.

Answer (score 0):

La cuestion no es que sea *finito* o *infinito* sino de cuando la condicion se cumple o no, hagamos un pequeño ejemplo con un  *if/else*

```
i = input('ingresa un numero')
if i>6:
     print(f'{i} es mayor que 6')
else:
     print('es menor')
```

si `i = 7` se cumplira la condicion, si es menor entrara al *else*, lo mismo pasa con el while, solo que el while verificara la condicion siempre (cada vez que termine el ciclo), y si añades el *else* lo haces para indicarle que haga algo en esa ocasion, ejemplo

```
i=0
while i<5:
     print('es menor que 5')
     i+=1
else:
     print('el numero es mayor que 5')
```

lo mismo si lo quieres hacer con un *True/False*

```
i = 0
valor=True
while valor:
     print('es True')
     if i>5:
          valor = False
else:
     print('el numero es mayor que 5 y valor es False')
```