# Iteracion en lista Python

Tags: python, bucles

Mi codigo es:

```
scripts = [
    ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"],
    ["Tomate", "Aji", "Aguacate"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
]

for index, sublist in enumerate(scripts):
    if "Aji" in sublist: 
        print(f"FOUND {index}")
        
    else:
        print("No found")
```

Resultado:

```
No found
FOUND 1
No found
No found
No found
```

Cuando realizo una iteracion solo con el FOUND sale bien porque solo aparece una vez, pero, cuando le agrego el "else" aparece muchas veces (muchas mas si tengo mas en la lista).

Mi pregunta es: **es posible hacer que el *else* solo aparezca una vez? Ya que recorre toda la lista y no es lo que quiero.**

Por ejemplo: si sabe que se encuentra el FOUND que solo se muestre una vez, si sabe que no hay en ninguno que el NO FOUND solo se muestre una vez.

Comment: No entiendo qué es lo que quieres que tu código haga. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y explicar lo que esperas que te devuelva el código?

Comment: Creo que para lo que quieres lo que debes hacer es salir del bucle tan pronto como hayas encontrado la primera coincidencia. Eso lo logras poniendo un `break` tras el `print("FOUND")` (y quitas el `else`). Además necesitas "recordar" de alguna forma si has salido del bucle porque has encontrado, o porque se agotaron las iteraciones. Puedes tener un booleano `encontrado`, inicialmente a `False`, que pondrías a `True` justo antes del `break`. Entonces, tras el bucle, podrías poner `if not encontrado: print("NOT FOUND")`

Comment: Te puedes ahorrar la variable booleana que mencionaba en mi anterior comentario si usas una estructura `for...else`, pero es algo poco habitual y un tanto confuso, pues Python es el único lenguaje (hasta donde yo sé) que permite esa estructura, lo que suele confundir a quien no conoce bien el lenguaje. Si quieres más detalles sobre esta idea mira [esta otra respuesta mía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/440649/7123) sobre la estructura `while...else`. La estructura `for...else` es análoga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad en tu código el `FOUND` también aparecerá más de una vez si en varias sublistas está la palabra `Banana`.

Si quieres que te diga al final si se ha encontrado o no, puedes hacerlo por ejemplo así:

```
scripts = [
    ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"],
    ["Tomate", "Aji", "Aguacate"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Banana"],
]
find_word = False
for index, sublist in enumerate(scripts):
    if "Banana" in sublist: 
        print(f"FOUND {index}")
        print(sublist)
        find_word = True

print(find_word)
```

Esto te devolvería:

```
FOUND 0  # Encontrado en el índice 0
['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange']
FOUND 4  # Encontrado en el índice 0
['Fruta7', 'Fruta8', 'Banana']
True
```

En caso de que la palabra no estuviese en ninguna sublista:

```
scripts = [
    ["Mango", "Apple", "Orange"],
    ["Tomate", "Aji", "Aguacate"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
]
find_word = False
for index, sublist in enumerate(scripts):
    if "Banana" in sublist: 
        print(f"FOUND {index}")
        print(sublist)
        find_word = True

print(find_word)
```

Esto solo devolvería `False`

Si es necesario luego puedes convertir este `False` a 'No found'

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo tu estilo, lo mejor es usar la cláusula `else` del `for`:

```py
scripts = [
    ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"],
    ["Tomate", "Aji", "Aguacate"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
]

for index, sublist in enumerate(scripts):
    if "Aji" in sublist: 
        print(f"FOUND {index}")
        break
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Observa que el `else` está identado en el nivel del `for`. Si se encuentra `"Aji"`, con `break` se sale del `for` si pasar por el `else`. Si se termina el `for` si encontrar nada, se ejecuta el `else`.

En python existen dos funciones que pueden serte de utilidad: [all()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#all) y [any()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#any).

Para chequear si `"Aji"` está en alguna lista, se puede hacer del siguiente modo:

```py
if any("Aji" in sublist for sublist in scripts):
    print("FOUND")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Como quieres saber en qué sublista está, tenemos que complicarlo un poco:

```py
founds = (index for index, sublist in enumerate(scripts) if "Aji" in sublist)

if (index := next(founds, -1)) >= 0:
    print(f"FOUND {index}")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

En `founds` tenemos un iterador de `index` de sublistas que tienen la palabra `"Aji"`. Para extraer el primer elemento se usa `next()`, con valor por defecto `-1` si no existe ningún elemento. `index` nos dará la posición de la sublista, o dará `-1` si no hubiera ninguna.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un **booleano** para comprobar si se ha encontrado, y un **break** para salir del bucle una vez se haya encontrado.

```
encontrado = False

for index, sublist in enumerate(scripts):

if "Aji" in sublist: 
    print(f"FOUND {index}")
    encontrado = True
    break # Termina la ejecución del bucle

if not encontrado:
    print(f"NOT FOUND")
```

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo usar el método [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) de las listas de Python para encontrar el índice de un elemento en la lista.

Ese método eleva una excepción "ValueError" si no encuentra el elemento, así que necesitarás un `try-catch` para evitar ese error.

Puedes guardar el indice del elemento y hacer `break` una vez se encuentra el elemento, así evitas hacer más iteraciones de las necesarias, pero solo te encontrará la primera vez que aparece el elemento, y en la primera lista. No tengo claro tus intenciones con ese código, pero espero que el ejemplo de abajo te ayude:

```py
scripts = [
    ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange"],
    ["Tomate", "Aji", "Aguacate"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
    ["Fruta7", "Fruta8", "Fruta9"],
]

sublistIndex = None
foundIndex = None
for index, sublist in enumerate(scripts):
    try:
        foundIndex = sublist.index("Aguacate")
        sublistIndex = index
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        pass

if foundIndex:
    print("Found in sublist index {} at index {}".format(sublistIndex, foundIndex))
else:
    print("Not found")
```